# Command to cause potion effect when near certain blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to fake the effect of radiation by causing players to get various potion effects when they are near, or interact with, certain blocks. Specifically, I would like these potions

minecraft:glowing -- color: 9740385 -- is good effect -- PotionID: 24

minecraft:nausea -- color: 5578058 -- is bad effect -- PotionID: 9

minecraft:poison -- color: 5149489 -- is bad effect -- PotionID: 19

when players are near block immersiveengineering:ore:5

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. Question answered? If not, please use Google and the Minecraft wiki, like you should have done before asking this. Look also here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Actually, yes, my question was answered. It is possible. I did not want to beat my head against the wall trying to figure out how to do it if it could not be done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, try this:

First look at the block you want to use for the effects
Now type this in chat: ( [tab] = press tab to get the coörds of the block. )

*/summon armor_stand [tab] [tab] [tab] {CustomName:"P.E",Invisible:1b,Small:1b,Marker:1b,NoGravity:1b}*

Next place down a repeating command block that's always active
Put this command in the command block:

*/execute @e[name=P.E,r=5] ~ ~ ~ /execute @a[r=5] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players tag @s add P.E*

Now place down other repeating command blocks that are always active
And put these command in it:

*/execute @a[tag=P.E] ~ ~ ~ /effect @s 24 1 0 true*

*/execute @a[tag=P.E] ~ ~ ~ /effect @s 9 1 0 true*

*/execute @a[tag=P.E] ~ ~ ~ /effect @s 19 1 0 true*

Add this into an other command block to remove the P.E tag:

*/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=P.E] remove P.E*

When they are more than 5 blocks away from the block the effects will only last 1 second more. **Multiplayer Friendly & you can target unlimited blocks with the 1st command (summon)**

also no plugins needed for this only MC 1.12 or 1.11